# ListView shows only the last element throughout the rows

Tags: android, list, listview

I have a ListAdapter to which I pass a List. When I iterate through it and try to assign the values to TextViews and ImageViews, only the elements of the last item in the list get displayed.

Here is my code:-

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Activity activity;
    private List<News> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public Context myContext;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public Context mContext;
    public ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String myTitle, description, pubdate, pubName, mycomments, myviews,bitmapurl;
     static class LazyViewHolder
     {
         TextView title;
         TextView description;
         ImageView thumb_image;
         WebView imageWebView;
         TextView pubDate;
     }
      public LazyAdapter(Context ctx, List<News> newsListy) 
      {
            mContext = ctx;
            data=newsListy;
            inflater =LayoutInflater.from(ctx);

            imageLoader=new ImageLoader(ctx);
        }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View vi=convertView;
        LazyViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(com.zevenpooja.attini.R.layout.list_row,null);

        viewHolder = new LazyViewHolder();

        viewHolder.title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(com.zevenpooja.attini.R.id.title); // title
        viewHolder.description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(com.zevenpooja.attini.R.id.description); // artist name
       viewHolder.pubDate = (TextView)vi.findViewById(com.zevenpooja.attini.R.id.txtPubDate);


     //   List<News> song = new ArrayList<News>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) 
        {
            myTitle = data.get(i).getTitle().toString();
            description = data.get(i).getDescription().toString();
            bitmapurl = data.get(i).getNewsBigImage().toString();
            pubdate = data.get(i).getPublishedDate().toString();





         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myTitle);

         int j = 0;
         while ((j = sb.indexOf(" ", j + 40)) != -1) {
             sb.replace(j, j + 1, "\n");
         }

         viewHolder.title.setText(sb.toString());

         //DEscription
         description = description.substring(0, Math.min(description.length(), 50));
         viewHolder.description.setText(description);

         //Date
         final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
         final String NEW_FORMAT = "MMMM dd, yy";

         String newDate ="";

         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
         try
         {
            Date d = sdf.parse(pubdate);
            sdf.applyLocalizedPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
            newDate = sdf.format(d);
            viewHolder.pubDate.setText(newDate);
        } 
         catch (java.text.ParseException e)
         {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

         //IMAGE
         viewHolder.thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(com.zevenpooja.attini.R.id.list_image); // thumb image
           imageLoader.DisplayImage(bitmapurl, viewHolder.thumb_image);
        }


        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: where is your listview and where you are setting data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `for` loop and replace `data.get(i)` with `data.get(position)`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your for that is iterating through all your data elements.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final News news = data.get(position);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

**getView**

```
    View row = convertView;
    // get adapter value 
    News newsListy = this.data.get(i)
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_post_wall, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();


        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    }


    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

error in your for cycle:  you code is cycle valuation. at the end of ,your myTitle is also the dataList last item data.